# Online VBScript compiler or how to execute VBScript in browser

Tags: windows, web, vbscript

I've written some VBS code and want to execute it. The problem is that it's a completely Windows-orientated script (so not for ASP) while I'm on Mac, so I can't test it. I don't have a Windows PC or laptop for now. I've could have installed Windows on Mac using Boot Camp or run Windows using VirtualBox, but I don't want to do that now. Is there any solution to execute VBScript code in web interface or using Cross Over on Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It used to be that IE would support VBScript but beginning with IE11 Microsoft stopped supporting web based support for VBScript.

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/dn384057(v=vs.94)

VBScripts are executed either by WScript.exe (popups) or CScript.exe (command window). You will need the WScript, which acts as the object library. Sorry that I cannot help you further.

C:> wscript.exe "C:/PopUp.vbs"  (This is executing from the command line)

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click the desktop.
2. Select create->Text document.
3. Open the created text document.
4. Write the following code:

   ```
   <script language='VBScript'>
       'Put your code there...
       CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("%{F4}")
   </script>
   ```
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.
6. Save your file with the extension ".hta".

---

File is ready to open.

BE CAREFUL!!!

VBScript may be very dangerous for you system.